# Javascript regex to match string not preceded by

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen a few answers that deal with this question but was unable to get them to work.

What is a regex that would match `"LOGGED_IN"` but not match `"NOT_LOGGED_IN"`?

Comment: This isn't something to use RegEx for, use `.indexOf()` to check for a "NOT". That said, `/^LOGGED\_IN/i` should work fine

Comment: You don't need lookbehind for this. Just match a word boundary ([`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary)).

Answer (score 0):

^LOGGED_IN$ is first to come to mind

Comment: This only works if the string is at the beginning. It won't work if he's trying to distinguish "Joe is LOGGED_IN" from "Joe is NOT_LOGGED_IN"

Comment: True, but that was not specified in his question